# Why $3X^3+12X^2+30$ is irreducible on $\mathbb Q$ and not in $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I don't understand why $3X^3+12X^2+30$ is irreducible on $\mathbb Q$ and not in $\mathbb Z$ ? Indeed, don't we have $$3X^3+12X^2+30=3(X^3+4X^2+10)$$ is a factorization in $\mathbb Q$ ? If it's a factorization in $\mathbb Z$, why it is not consider as a factorization in $\mathbb Q$ ?

Answer (score 5):

Because $3$ is invertible in $\mathbb Q$ and not in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: @Rick, constant polynomial $3$ is invertible over $\mathbb Q$, but irreducible over $\mathbb Z$. Thus your polynomial has decomposition into irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb Z$, but not over $\mathbb Q$. See [Gauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_%28polynomial%29).

Comment: You would ignore a factor of $1$ and $-1$ because they have reciprocals, and are factors of everything.  $3$ has a reciprocal in $\mathbb{Q}$ so is ignored as a separate factor; $3$ has no reciprocal in $\mathbb{Z}$ so the fact that it is a factor of the polynomial is more important in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your final comment on Thomas' (now-deleted) answer is worth keeping here. It really clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 2):

$X^3+4X+10$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ which is seen, for example, by the Einsenstein criterion of irreducibility, and stay irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ if it is multiplied for an arbitrary unit (i.e. invertible element) of $\mathbb Q$, in particular for your $3$. However the constant polynomial $p(X)=3$ (which is invertible in $\mathbb Q[X]$, having as inverse $q(X)=\frac13$) is not invertible in $\mathbb Z[X]$ because the only units of $\mathbb Z$ are $1$ and $-1$.